# Get the number of distinct row after distinct

Tags: mysql, sql

Trying to get the number of row after distinct. Press this [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T26Uv.png] for examples.

Comment: Please post your sample input, and expected output with that input data. And using formatted text instead of image. P/S your request seems could be easily achieved using a basic `COUNT()....GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: But if i use `COUNT()....GROUP BY` clause, I will get 
`AGENT_CODE | ORD_AMOUNT | CUST_CODE`
`1                        |  500                    |    C00022         `

Comment: You means you only want the row that only appear once? If you show your expected output, we could understand your requirement better. FYI, you could search for `HAVING` clause to apply your condition `distinct row after distinct`

Comment: My expected output is the Results of the image above. To show that the first row have 2 duplicated under the column count and while others dont have duplicate so they only have 1

Comment: Then could you please show your query using `COUNT()`? How could it be not the right query for your case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple grouping of a subquery ought to do it.

```
SELECT agent_code, ord_amount, cust_code, count(*)
  FROM (SELECT distinct agent_code, ord_amount, cust_code
          FROM orders
         WHERE agent_code = 'A0002')
GROUP BY agent_code, ord_amount, cust_code
```

There are more complex approaches as alternatives but this seems the simplest.